# Wordpress - Home link is not working on blog page

Tags: php, wordpress, conflict

I've just setup a menu in Wordpress, when I navigate to the page http://agilisaexpress.com.br/blog/, if I click the Home link or the Logo's link, it won't redirect to the home page. In the status bar it displays the full site url, I don't know what's going on. The Home link works in any page, except on the Blog page.

Doing my homework, found out that the conflict is being generated by javascript. The class `.header` calls the following code:

```
$('a.header').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#header').offset().top - '80'}, 1000, function() {
        scrollingfn();
    });
    return false;
});
```

So if I add a jQuery noconflict, it might solve the problem?

Comment: That's probably because you've purchased a parallax theme where the navigation menu items use `#element` as opposed to `http://www.domain.tld/page`. The reason it doesn't do anything on the blog page is that the header is already at the top and you can't scroll the page anyway. Also, there is javascript supressing the default click event of your logo. Lastly, your page is generating an error. Check the console of your web inspector.

Comment: Actually I removed the `#header` alement and the problem persisted.

Comment: Right now I even removed the php that was calling the url, and placed the full url on its palce, same result.

Answer (score 0):

May be due to the javascript error which causing to go to home page.

Comment: The only error I'm seeing is `Uncaught No element defined.GMaps @ gmaps.js:203`.

Comment: Just found out the conflict is related to the class `.header`, that class is probably using jquery too, to get the sliding effect.